# how works a variable with multiple strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the following code:

```js
let str = ("George Washington", "Abe Lincoln", "Kanye West");

function fullNameArgsToObject() {
  let str = "";
  let obj = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i], "flag");
    str = arguments[i]
  }
}

fullNameArgsToObject(str);
```

the output of this is: "Kanye West flag"
but why is it only returning Kanye West?
why is not printing the first two strings? im kind of new with js, thanks!

Comment: Try doing `console.log(str);`

Comment: What do you think `str` is?

Comment: `let str = ("George Washington", "Abe Lincoln", "Kanye West");` would set `str` to `'Kanye West'`

Comment: Instead of a tuple use an array: change the let 
str = ("George Washington", "Abe Lincoln", "Kanye West");
to
let str = ["George Washington", "Abe Lincoln", "Kanye West"];
Additionally use parameters in the function declaration:
 function fullNameArgsToObject(strs) {
  let str = "";
  let obj = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    console.log(strs[i], "flag");
    str = strs[i]
  }
}